# divide multiple series by each other in grafana

Tags: graphite, grafana

I'm using Grafana for a dashboard, and I have the following queries:

```
A) scale(networkstats.day.$Network.widget_requests, 0.001)
B) divideSeries(networkstats.day.$Network.campaigns_spend, #A)
```

and showing only query B.

I'd like to show this exact graph for all networks, and not just a single one.

is there a way to divide a set of series by an id? (in our case network)

thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `$Network` is the template variable defined in your dashboard having multiple values you can generate:

- multiple rows with graph panel for every value of $Network setting
  **`Repeat for`** `$Network` in grafana `Row Options`

or

- multiple graph panels in same row setting **`Repeat Panel`** `$Network` in graph options editor in `General` tab.